# Is there any hindu sect which does not believe in rebirth?

Tags: belief, philosophy, rebirth, sects, afterlife

There are so many diverse practices and sects in Hinduism. Every kind of possible beliefs are available in one sect or another. This is conceptual richness of Hinduism.

Now, every Hindu sect/philosophy which I encountered so far believes in rebirth.

Just for curiosity on belief-diversity, **Is there any sect/philosophy in Hinduism, which does not believe in rebirth?**

Comment: no, all Hindu sects believe in rebirth. It is one of the definitions of being Hindu - belief in God, belief in the Vedas, belief in rebirth.

Comment: I think "Charvaka" philosophy may not be believing in rebirth. They seem more like modern thinking of "ek pal ka jeena, fir to hai jaana!" @SwamiVishwananda,

Comment: **atheistic Hindu philosophies**  like sankhya,mimansa etc have what stance on rebirth?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda (Purva) Mimamsakas were divided over the existence of Brahman.

Comment: A word Hindu or Hinduism is a cultural term.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan purvas are classified as an indian philosophy, not as vedantists. All modern Hindus (Vedantists) are followers of Vyasa, therefore all believe in rebirth.

Answer (score 1):

***[ChArvaka](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charvaka)*** is one such school.

> In 8th century CE Jaina literature, Saddarsanasamuccaya by Haribhadra,[25] Lokayata is stated to be the Hindu school where there is "no God, no samsara (rebirth), no karma, no duty, no fruits of merit, no sin."

and also,

> **Consciousness and afterlife**
>   Charvaka school of Hinduism did not believe in karma, rebirth or an afterlife. To them, all attributes that represented a person, such as thinness, fatness etc., resided in the body. The Sarvasiddhanta Samgraha states the Charvaka position as follows,[52]
>
> There is no other world other than this;
>   There is no heaven and no hell;
>   The realm of Shiva and like regions,
>   are invented by stupid imposters.
>   — Sarvasiddhanta Samgraha, Verse 8[52]

Comment: Charvaka is NOT a school of Hinduism. That is because they didnt accept the Vedas

Comment: @Ikshvaku, so you have any definite reference which suggests that "Hindu = accepting Vedas". Many Hindus don't know anything about Veda, let alone accepting it. Besides read the above wiki reference which suggests Charvaka as Hindus.

Comment: Which Hindus dont accept Vedas as authority?

Comment: Charvakas aren't Hindu because they didnt consider themselves Hindu; they explicitly rejected the Vedas. And that text you referenced above is a Jain text

Comment: @Ikshvaku, probably because most people don't even know the origin of the word Hindu. They think people who follow the Hindu religion are called Hindus :( , and it is just associated with those in present day India.

Comment: @ram And who are the followers of the Hindu religion? The answer is, those who follow the religion directly based on the Vedas; those who accept the authority of the Vedas

Comment: @Ikshvaku, that is not 'Hindu' religion. That is veda/sanatana dharma. According to those who use the word Hindu, it is the religion which is mostly followed by people in India. And those people don't care if it is based on vedas or not.. as long as it is ancient, written in sanskrit, talks about mystic things, and is different from western religions. I'm not arguing against your point about charvaka. this is just semantics.

Comment: carvakism is not Hindu.

Comment: Charvaka is classfied as an Indian philosophy, not a Hindu philosophy. All modern day Hindus (Vedantists) whether dualists, monists, or in-between, are followers of Vyasa and as such assert rebirth.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, All, -- though politically incorrect, "Hindu = Indian". The words' etymologies are from the same origin. There is no rule of one has to be believe in VyAsa/Vedas to be Hindu. My Indian friend doesn't believe in any God, and he doesn't have any clue about Veda except he has heard the name. This doesn't make him non-Hindu. ChArvaka originated in Indian subcontinent and Wikipedia & its internal sources correctly refers them as Hindus.

Comment: @iammilind No. they are an Indian philosophy. Wikipedia doesn't define who a Hindu is....all 'Hindus' are followers of Vyasa. Jains as well as Charvakas are not orthodox. If you don't follow the vedas, you're not a Hindu. You may be an Indian, you may follow caste laws, but if you don't follow the vedas, you're not a Hindu.