# Is there a sect in Hinduism that reject reincarnation?

Tags: sects

There are many sects in Hinduism that have their own beliefs. So it there any sect that reject reincarnation.

Comment: Charvaka rejects rebirth and afterlife. The six schools of sanatana dharma do not.

Comment: @GIRIBLR it is a separate philosophy and not a sect in Hinduism or sanatana dharma.

Comment: @GIRIBLR sect for example ISKON, and Araya samajh

Comment: See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/is-there-any-hindu-sect-which-does-not-believe-in-rebirth

Comment: @GIRIBLR okk thanks,

Comment: None other than Charvaka, if you consider them a "Hindu sect" (which they are not btw).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any hindu sect which does not believe in rebirth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/is-there-any-hindu-sect-which-does-not-believe-in-rebirth)